# How to assign javascript variable to ruby variable using AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to assign JavaScript variable to ruby variable through ajax request so I wrote following code in JavaScript function:

```
var timezone = jstz.determine();  
var encoded = encodeURIComponent('<%= groups_path%>'+'?@myActivity=' +  <%=@activity.id%>+'&time_zone='+timezone.name());  
    $.ajax({  
            type: "get",  
            url: encoded,  
            dataType: "JSON",  
            success: function(data)  
            {  
            <%=@timezone=params[:time_zone]%>  
            }  
        });
```

But it is giving `GET http://0.0.0.0:3001/%2Fgroups%3F%40myActivity%3D1%26time_zone%3DAsia%2FCalcutta 404 (Not Found)` error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puja,

You are doing something wrong, You dont understand well about javascript language and Ruby language.

When you will see your JS code in browser then you will see like below

```
$.ajax({  
            type: "get",  
            url: encoded,  
            dataType: "JSON",  
            success: function(data)  
            {  
            }  
        });
```

Because `<%=@timezone=params[:time_zone]%>`   it is Ruby code that will run before rendering html page to browser, then there will be static JS and HTML script will render to browser

First try to understand the flow of Ruby and Javascript and HTMl thne you can have better understating

Answer (score 0):

You got things a little mixed up there.

The javascript you are trying to run, so I assume, would be run on the client side. You got no Ruby over there, only on the server side.

What you typically do is, you write Javascript that you then render in your views (which means it gets sent to the client side).
You can insert predefined values (like paths) into your template by naming them my_client_side_code.**js.erb**.

When you make an AJAX request to your server, you can write a response from the server to the client (in Javascript).
That makes the client evaluate whatever Javascript you provided in the server response. In that case, you can use Ruby variables in the usual ERB fashion.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html
For a full guide, you can refer the the rails guides!

Good luck!